# Is there any way to store instance variable name inside of instance string?

Tags: python, class

I'm making a Matrix class and when I pretty-print the matrix, I would like there to be the matrix name. So for example

```
Bob = Matrix("2&3&4@4&5&6@6&7&8")
print(Bob)
```

Output:

```
---Matrix Bob---
   | 2 3 4 |
   | 4 5 6 |
   | 6 7 8 |
----------------
```

Is there any way to do this, without passing the name as a parameter?

I have no idea except for code file scraping aaand... not a good idea.

Comment: Not possible. Objects normally don't "know" what variable they're assigned to.

Comment: Objects can have more than one name, or no name. It's impossible. But you can add an attribute to the object.

Answer (score -1):

Objects aren't able to see the the variable they're assigned to